# INQ Cloud Touch debugging

Tags: android, debugging

Does some one tried to debug this kind of device, what driver are you using to make him appear in debug mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this driver:
http://new.inqmobile.com/_includes/uploads/software-update/software-update-1.exe

Except when I do a adb devices it doesn't show up. Hope it works for you though.

Edit: I got it to work by adding 0x2314 on its own line to %userprofile%.android\adb_usb.ini and restarting the adb server with adb kill-server