# INQ Cloud touch vendor ID

Tags: android, debugging, touch, cloud, adb

Does anyone know the VendorID for this device?
Another answer here [INQ Cloud Touch debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467681/inq-cloud-touch-debugging) mentions adding "2314" to %userprofile%.android\adb_usb.ini on Windows systems, however I am using Ubuntu and am unsure if this is value is actually the Vendor ID or not. And adding this to the 70-android.rules does not seem to get the device recognized via "adb devices". Any info would be greatly appreciated, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INQ Cloud Touch (and possibly other INQ devices) use an alternate version of adb, available here:

http://www.fileserve.com/file/QV59ZeS/adb

Use this in place of the standard adb and follow the tutorial from Android Developers:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up

Answer (score 2):

This command:

```
lsusb
```

on Ubuntu will list all the connected usb devices with their id.

Comment: Thanks very much, that did confirm that 2314 is the correct vendor id, though the device is still not reconized by adb devices... Thanks again